# What is the sense of static variables in Java?

Tags: java

What is the sense of making or not making a variable **static**? Why can't **non-static** variables be accessed from a **static method**?

Comment: Why not just `System.out.println("This... ");`?

Comment: Because this is an example. I would have needed some more code to make a realistic example

Comment: Then perhaps show an example where you shouldn't simply do that :)

Comment: I don't think that's useful

Comment: @Galgo the answer for what you posted is Andy's answer: you don't even need a variable. Since we don't know what your **actual** situation is, we can't recommend anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Since string is always the same, should I make it static

YES. To be specific make it like this:

```
public class A implements ActionListener {

    public static final String MY_STRING = "This is a string"; // can be private also

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        System.out.println(MY_STRING);
    }
}
```

Thanks for the feedback and I see a good point of Tom's comment :

> Extracting everything is not a programming convention and doing
>   something must make sense and not just "cause no harm -- Tom

I would like to clarify that this answer is only intended to OP's situation. However it can be no-good as what Andy mentioned earlier : `making the code harder to grok. If there is no "semantic" meaning to the value`. In conclusion this answer might not be suitable in most similar case.

Comment: Just in case OP blindly believes what this answer says: no, the answer is not "yes", it is "it depends". Defining Strings as constants just one can is not always the way to go.

Comment: I do not think that following some programming convention can cause harm.

Comment: Extracting everything is not a programming convention and doing something must make sense and not just "cause no harm".

Comment: Btw. following conventions and patterns when not appropriated can lead to anti-patterns.

Comment: Wait, I never said do it all the time It just happen that I believe this is suitable to OP's situation. Yes, I do agree that using conventions when not appropriated is not a good idea.

Comment: It's not appropriate to the OP's situation. There is no reason to extract that literal, used in a single place, into a constant (or a variable), and even less to a public one. It only makes the code a little bit harder to read, and doesn't bring any advantage.

Comment: It doesn't cause no harm: adding a constant introduces indirection, making the code harder to grok. If there is no "semantic" meaning to the value (as in, if it has no more meaning than just "the log message that I will print at some point in the code"), don't extract a constant, or even a variable.

Answer (score 0):

If it's static, it won't be garbage collected. Moreover, if it's a local variable, it shouldn't be accessible to other methods.

Comment: Yes, but if it is assigned from a string literal, it won't be garbage collected either, because the value is in the string pool.

Comment: Are you sure? Even though the string isn't used anymore, at the end of the method?

Comment: Yes, quite sure.

Answer (score -2):

The JVM garbage collector can cache (or deduplicate) Strings, so you shouldn't worry too much about this.

Comment: I used a string, but the code was just an example. I would have needed to write some more useless code to make it realistic

Comment: @Tom That's no news, I read that long ago.

Comment: @Patrick the garbage collector doesn't cache anything.

Comment: There was an option UseStringCache in previous Java versions. I didn't invent anything.

Comment: Patrick, can you point us to source of your statement? String deduplication via `interning` has nothing to do with GC, except fact that interned strings are  not GC collectable in JDK < 1.7 (stored in permgen) - is that what you `read long ago`?

Comment: When you really had "UseStringCache" in mind, then I would remove the "cache" and just keep "deduplicate". The GC doesn't cache these Strings itself, but moves them to the String pool. (I also haven't read that this option is obsolete in newer version, thus it should still work)